# Remove all occurences of a value from a nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a nested dictionary as the following.

```
myDict= {
          "id": 10,
          "state": "MY LIST",  
          "Stars":
          { 
            "BookA": {
                     "id": 10,
                     "state": "new book",  
                     "Mystery": {
                                "AuthorA": 
                                {
                                "id": "100",                                
                                "state": "thriller"
                                },
                                 "AuthorB": 
                                {
                                "id": "112",                                
                                "state": "horror"
                                }
                             },
                     "Thriller": {
                                "Store1": 
                                {
                                "id": "300",                                
                                "state": "Old"
                                }                                
                           }
                  }
            }
        }
```

I want to return a dictionary which has all of the "state": "text" removed. So that means, I want to remove all the "state" fields and have an output as below.
**I want it to be generic method as the dictionary could be nested on many levels.**

```
myDict= 
{
          id: 10,
          "Stars":
          { 
            "BookA": {
                     "id": 10  
                     "Mystery": {
                                "AuthorA": 
                                {
                                "id": "100"                               

                                },
                                 "AuthorB": 
                                {
                                "id": "112"
                                }
                             },
                     "Thriller": {
                                "Store1": 
                                {
                                "id": "300"
                                }                                
                           }
                  }
            }
```

I tried the following but it doesnt seem to work. It only removes the "state": "MY LIST". May someone help me to resolve the issue?

```
    def get(self):
        removelist= ["state"]
        new_dict = {}
        for key, item in myDict.items():
            if key not in removelist:
                new_dict.update({key: item})
       return new_dict
```

It doesnt remove all the "state" values.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [DFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search):

```
def remove_keys(d, keys):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        return {k: remove_keys(v, keys) for k, v in d.items() if k not in keys}
    else:
        return d
```

The idea is to remove recursively the keys from subtrees: for every subtree that is a nested dict, return a dict without the keys to remove, using a dict comprehension; for every leaf (that is a single value), just return the value.

Test:

```
from pprint import pprint
pprint(remove_keys(myDict, ['state']))
```

Output:

```
{'Stars': {'BookA': {'Mystery': {'AuthorA': {'id': '100'},
                                 'AuthorB': {'id': '112'}},
                     'Thriller': {'Store1': {'id': '300'}},
                     'id': 10}},
 'id': 10}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It works!! Thats for the clear explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you aren't handling the nested dictionaries.

```
def get(self):
        removelist= ["state"]
        new_dict = {}
        for key, item in myDict.items():
            if key not in removelist:
                new_dict.update({key: item})
            if isinstance(item, dict):
                # You'll need to handle this use case.
       return new_dict
```

To elaborate, lets look back at your dictionary:

```
myDict= {
    "id": 10, # int
    "state": "MY LIST", # string
    "Stars": { # dictionary
        "BookA": {
            "id": 10, # int
            "state": "new book", # string  
            "Mystery": { # dictionary
                "AuthorA":  {
                    "id": "100",                                
                    "state": "thriller"
                },
                "AuthorB":  {
                    "id": "112",                                
                    "state": "horror"
                }
            },
            "Thriller": {
                "Store1":  {
                    "id": "300",                                
                    "state": "Old"
                }                                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I commented in the types for clarity. Your code is currently parsing myDict and ignoring the key "state". Once you hit the value "Stars", you need to parse that dictionary to also ignore the key "state".

Comment: I am not sure on what you mean. May you please elaborate it, I am really new to python and any help is appreciated.

Comment: I elaborated on the answer. You'll need to handle the nested dictionaries with additional code.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. :)